# How to extend a class with mapbox-gl FullscreenButton

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mapbox-gl-js

I want to wrap the standard mapbox-gl FullscreenButton, see [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/adef501c464d51b328bdcdea355008aea9ab8ae1/src/ui/control/fullscreen_control.js), to add following features:

1. ***needsclick*** should be add to the button class to avoid Fastclick errors.
2. Instead of just making the mapcontainer fullscreen, the button
   should make the entire document page fullscreen (so also other divs
   etc.).

I tried the following: [fiddle](https://jsbin.com/peravo/2/edit?js,console,output). Somehow you first have to hit return in the ES6/Babel window before the code will run and the map shows...

Problems I ran into:

1. The '**onAdd**' method somehow triggers this error:

> "TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is
>   not of type 'Node'.
>       at e.addControl (https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.36.0/mapbox-gl.js:390:3490)
>       at jekuwak.js:69:5"

2.
 When **1** is solved (I workaround by adding **needsclick** via Chrome Devtools), the `this._mapContainer.webkitRequestFullscreen()` is triggered.

What do I change to get the full page fullscreen instead of just the mapcontainer?

Comment: @sgelb As this is pretty similar to a question of mine you answered before, you might want to peek into this?! Thx!

Comment: People don't get notified of @mentions on SO unless they're participating in the thread.

Comment: I see..., that's a pity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #1:

```
const fs = new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl();
map.addControl(fs)
fs._fullscreenButton.classList.add('needsclick');
```

For #2:

The `FullscreenControl` is not extensible in this way – it has been designed to operate on the map canvas and changing that would probably be more trouble than just writing the functionality you want from scratch. If you want to make your whole `window` fullscreen, I suggest you implement the full-screen functionality independently of mapboxgl. If you want to be able to use the icons provided with mapboxgl you can add the appropriate CSS classes to the element you create.